# Custom Reshaping a dataframe in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have below dataframe

```
library(reshape2)    
dat = data.frame('Para' = c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'), 'Val' = c(.3, .45, .34, 12, 67))
```

Now I tried to reshape this as below

```
dcast(dat, Para~Val)
```

This gives below result

```
  Para  1  2  3  4  5
1    A  1  2 NA NA NA
2    B NA NA  3  4  5
>
```

However I wanted to have below shape

[image]

Is there any function available to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another column which has the sequence number and then pivot

```
library(reshape2)
dat$s=ave(dat$Para,dat$Para,FUN=seq)
dcast(dat,Para~s,value.var="Val")

  Para    1     2  3
1    A 0.30  0.45 NA
2    B 0.34 12.00 67
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a column with the within-group row number first, then use `dcast` or other pivoting function:

```r
library(data.table)
dcast(data = setDT(dat), Para ~ rowid(Para), value.var = "Val") 
#Credits to @Yuriy Saraykin 

#   Para    1     2  3
#1:    A 0.30  0.45 NA
#2:    B 0.34 12.00 67
```

Or in `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  mutate(rown = row_number(), .by = Para) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "rown", values_from = "Val")
```

Comment: `dcast(data = setDT(dat), Para ~ rowid(Para), value.var = "Val")`

Comment: Not a data.table here, thanks for the simplification! I'll add that instead if that's alright with you

Answer (score 2):

A base R option with `reshape` + `ave`

```
reshape(
    transform(
        dat,
        id = ave(seq_along(Para), Para, FUN = seq_along)
    ),
    direction = "wide",
    idvar = "Para",
    timevar = "id"
)
```

gives

```
  Para Val.1 Val.2 Val.3
1    A  0.30  0.45    NA
3    B  0.34 12.00    67
```